# Why can't I bind a string?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Trying to wrap my old brain around WPF data binding.
Starting with the simplest scenario I could think of: An example online that worked, and I then simplified it.

I bound a simple `string` property to a `TextBlock`. Didn't work. When I then encapsulated that `string` inside a class of my own, it worked just fine!

Question: Why doesn't my `string` property work, but my class does?

```
<Window x:Class = "DataBindingOneWay.MainWindow" 
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Height = "350" Width = "600">

    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DataBindingOneWay
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public string? Name1 { get; set; } = "Paul";
        }

        public string? Name1 { get; set; } = "Peter";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new Employee();
            // DataContext = Name1;            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings operate on a data context that is set on elements deriving from `FrameworkElement` through the [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property. A [data context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0#data-context) is inherited in the tree of elements.

> When data binding is declared on XAML elements, they resolve data binding by looking at their immediate DataContext property. The data context is typically the binding source object for the binding source value path evaluation. You can override this behavior in the binding and set a specific binding source object value. If the DataContext property for the object hosting the binding isn't set, the parent element's DataContext property is checked, and so on, up until the root of the XAML object tree. In short, the data context used to resolve binding is inherited from the parent unless explicitly set on the object.

If there is no data context set or you need to refer to other elements as bindings source, you need to parameterize a [`Binding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) with [`Source`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.source?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

> Bindings can be configured to resolve with a specific object, as opposed to using the data context for binding resolution.

Let use review how to bind a property defined in your `MainWindow`. There is no data context assigned initially. Therefore, all bindings to `Name1` will fail. What can we do? Here are a few options (there are more).

- Set the `DataContext` of `MainWindow` to `this` in code-behind.

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = this;            
  }
  ```

  This means all of the controls inherit the `MainWindow` as binding source. Consequently, we can bind the `Name1` property like this:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1}"/>
  ```

  Here `Name1` is the name (or [property path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.path?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)) of the property to bind on the binding source. So if we simply assigned `Name1` directly as `DataContext` of the window, then we would need to refer to the binding source itself, which is what `{Binding}` without a property path does.

  ```
  public MainWindow()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      DataContext = Name1;            
  }
  ```

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
  ```
- If you do not set a `DataContext`, you can still refer to elements using `ElementName` (requires an `x:Name` assigned to the target control) or `RelativeSource` which refers to an element in the element tree from the current element traversing parents until the root is reached.

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}"/>
  ```

  This example translates to: Search a binding source of type `MainWindow` up the element tree and if you find it, bind to its `Name1` property. As you can see, this does not necessarily need a data context if the property is defined on the control itself like in your example. Nevertheless, generally you would use the `DataContext` property if nothing prevents it, since it is conveniently inherited.

I hope you saw that there is nothing really magical about it. Regarding the binding sytax (which can be confusing), there is a good documentation that should take away lots of your question marks:

- [Binding path syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-6.0#binding-path-syntax)
- [Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0)

---

> I got to think: WHAT field, or, rather, property in the String Class actually holds the 'value' of the string?

**Bonus round:** You do not need to worry about that at all. You bind to the `string` property and WPF knows how to display it, no need to use internal structures, but for educational purposes, the documentation states:

> A string is a sequential collection of characters that's used to represent text. A `String` object is a sequential collection of `System.Char` objects that represent a string; a `System.Char` object corresponds to a UTF-16 code unit. The value of the `String` object is the content of the sequential collection of `System.Char` objects, and that value is immutable (that is, it is read-only).

The `string` type exposes this character array with its indexer property [`Chars`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.chars?view=net-6.0).

Comment: Actually, when I'm now rereading this, 'thatguy' had already (VERY clearly!) explained all that when I thanked another person! 
My apologies to 'thatguy': your response was spot on and I learned a lot from it!
Thank you so much for for elaborate and clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no `Name1` *inside* the object that you are binding to, when you bind to the string. That is, there is no `Name1` inside the `Name1` (what would be the result of `Name1.Name1`?). There is, however, a `Name1` inside the `Employee` object (what would be the result of `Employee.Name1`?)

Comment: Well, if it can't find Name1, then Name1.Name1 certainly doesn't work (I tried, of course).
But it got me to think "What if" I don't specify anything at all?
Just do a 
```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```
And ... that did the trick! (Not that I fully understand it ... yet ..., but okay).

Thanks for putting me on the right track!
Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access `Name1` property of `MainWindow` you should set `DataContext` to `this` (which is MainWindow instance) instead of `Name1`.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DataBindingOneWay
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            public string? Name1 { get; set; } = "Paul";
        }

        public string? Name1 { get; set; } = "Peter";

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;            
        }
    }
}
```

or from the other side - when you want the `Name1` property to be set as `DataContext` of `MainWindow` your binding should look like this:

```
<Window x:Class = "DataBindingOneWay.MainWindow" 
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   Height = "350" Width = "600">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation = "Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I tried that, but 'this' point to the Windows object, so if I do that, it puts in my TextBlock "DataBindingOneWay.MainWindow". 
But I think I found the answer: see below.

I appreciate your answer though! It helps me realize what's going on behind the curtain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jonathan's inspiring response, I got to think: WHAT field, or, rather, property in the String Class actually holds the 'value' of the string?

I played with everything, but nothing seemed to hold the actual string! (Weird).
That's where I got a crazy idea and tried simply

```
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

And

```
            DataContext = Name1;
```

And ... that worked!